# Rails 5 - Is there a way to log cache misses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Trying to debug why we're getting cache misses. In config/environments/production.rb we have asset fallback to true:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Every once in a while we see CPU surges and the culprit is nodejs, which we believe is firing due to this line (it's compiling assets when there's a miss).  Is there a way to log, either to the production log, or it's own, when an asset is missed, so we can figure out why it's not being added to the precompile locus?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: If the assets is precompiled, it should be delivered by your webserver (nginx, apache, etc), if rails has to compile it then it should appear on the production logs. But you are mixing caching with precompilation, those are different things. It is adviced to disable assets compilation on production, if some asset is not precompiled then the webserver will respond with a not found status code (it will appear on the web server errors log).

Comment: here's what i know empirically.  If i turn that config flag to false, i get a 500 when an asset is missed. If I turn it to true, i get a few giant nodejs processes, once in a while.  I believe what's happening is that 100% of assets are not being precompiled, triggering a miss, triggering a nodejs re-compile.  My original question is, how do i detect when this miss happens?

Comment: And should this question be reworded "is there a way to log precompile misses"?

Comment: request errors are logged on the web server errors log (nginx? apache? check the site-enabled config for your website if you don't know where the error log is)

Answer (score -1):

The directive you mentioned is for asset compiling, not caching. The config.rb directive for caching is (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true|false
```

This will not affect the caching of your static assets though, such as images, javascript files, or stylesheets. For that, you need to look at your web server settings and see why your static assets aren't being cached properly. You indicated that you get a spike once in a while. Are the spikes consistently spaced apart? If so then it may just be that your cache time to live is set too low and you need to bump it up. Do you see your spikes right after a deploy? If so, your assets may not be precompiled in that environment. You may even have both problems.